# how to do custom sorting i n MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to sort the result of a MySQL query in custom order, For that I have written this query but this is not returning the results in desired order:

```
select * from (
select assembly, party_id, count(party_id) as seats
from winner group by assembly, party_id) as newTable
group by assembly having max(seats) 
ORDER BY FIELD(assembly, 'National Assembly', 'Punjab Assembly', 'Sindh Assembly', 'KPK Assembly', 'Balochistan Assembly');
```

**Result of this query is:**

[image]

**But I want the result to be like this:**

[image]

Please tell what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Fix `'KPK Assembly'` so it matches the data:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(assembly, 'National Assembly', 'Punjab Assembly',
               'Sindh Assembly', 'KPK', 'Balochistan Assembly');
```

Comment: still not getting the required order

Comment: What are you getting?  That could be a good clue.  (Otherwise, Gordon's answer looks correct.)  Perhaps there are some spaces that should not be there?